# Odds ratio interpretation in logistic ordinal regression

Tags: logistic, ordered-logit

In my model I have my response/dependent variable (which is ordinal) and I wanted to explore whether a continuous predictor variable was associated with it, so I used ordinal logistic regression.

However, I'm a bit stuck of how to report/interpret the odd's ratio in my results

You can see that the predictor variable is on a much larger scale than my response

How do I interpret the odds?

That if my response is larger the predictor would be larger by 112%?

But then, I need to say how much larger my response would be

ANy help would be MASSIVELY appreciated

thanks[image]

Comment: Your response variable doesn't look very ordinal to me. It looks like you use a linear regression with a continuous outcome variable. Can you clarify what kind of model you used, perhaps with the code you used to fit it and some output?

Comment: Although it's possible to model continuous outcomes with ordinal regression, it does look like what's listed as the "Predictor variable" in your plot is better interpreted as ordinal rather than continuous. As @Noah suggests, please describe the model and the code, and also describe the underlying data and the hypothesis you want to test. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: hi thanks for responses! - apologies my upload was labelled incorrectly (blame my dyslexia) - I've now updated in the figure above - If you could please answer with reference tto that figure would be great thanks :)

Comment: @CameronKirk Usually we have the predictor on the x-axis and the response on the y-axis; it makes interpretation easier. Also, we still don't have any code or output. You only have one 2 and two 5s; might it be easier to just recode those as 3 and 4, respectively, to simplify interpretation?

Comment: It's hard to provide advice about how to interpret an odds ratio when we can't see the model that was used and the values that were returned. Software even can differ in the _direction_ implied by an odds ratio: some report the odds of being in a lower category, some the odds of being in a higher category. Please edit your question by copying that information into it, using the `{}` code tool to format that information for easy reading, and specifying what software and function you used.